# Truncate string on toggle in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this `container` which should change the color on `toggle`, and the strings inside it should be checked for the `length`. If the string is longer than 20 characters, `trucate` it and add "`...`" at the end. If it's shorter, leave it as it is. For some reason the `slice` does not work correctly in my case, it seems to cut more characters than it is set... Also, I can't seem to get the `innerHTML` to insert the new trucated string in place. I'm writing it in ES6 syntax, can't get it working in the fiddle - sorry about that. Any help appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/kpcaufg6/2/

```
constructor() {
  this.container = document.querySelector(".blue-bg");
  this.string = document.querySelector(".string").innerHTML;
  this.toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
}
events() {
  this.toggle.addEventListener("click", () => this.toggleMe());
}

truncateString(str, num) {
  if (str.length <= num) {
    return str
  }
  return str.slice(0, num) + '...'
}

toggleMe() {
  this.container.classList.toggle(".green-bg");

  if (container.classList.contains("blue-bg") && string.length >= 20) {
    this.string = this.truncateString(this.string, 20);
  } else {
    //just return string
  }
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by / think you mean by "ES6 syntax" - but that's not how you define js functions and because of that you're getting syntax errors in your fiddle `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'`

Comment: yeah I'm going through this tutorial, and the instructor says that using constructor etc. is a "better" way of writing the JS... Can't figure out which semicolon is missing though

Comment: Yes, you can `namespace` functions and use a constructor, but that's not how you do it.  Try these https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+constructor+pattern

Comment: Do you have a link to the tutorial?  Might be able to point out the bit you're missing in your own context.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it it seems helpful, tutorial is not public one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you present is not valid. For example, this piece of code ...

```
constructor() {
  this.container = document.querySelector(".blue-bg");
  this.string = document.querySelector(".string").innerHTML;
  this.toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
}
```

...lacks the `function` keyword. I'm not sure what it is you want to do and why in this case a `constructor` would be better, but here is a snippet inferred from your code. It uses [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation), meaning that a specific handler for an element is not necessary.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", toggle);

function toggle(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (origin.classList.contains("toggle")) {
    const container = document.querySelector(".blue-bg, .green-bg");
    if (container.classList.contains("green-bg")) {
      container.classList.replace("green-bg", "blue-bg");
    } else {
      container.classList.replace("blue-bg", "green-bg");
    }
    const stringBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".string");
    if (container.classList.contains("blue-bg")) {
      stringBoxes.forEach(box => {
        if (box.textContent.length >= 20) {
          box.textContent = box.textContent.slice(0, 20);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.blue-bg {
  background: lightblue;
}

.green-bg {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-bg">
  <p class="string">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus eveniet libero voluptate sunt distinctio iste ex, ratione, soluta, labore dolorem laboriosam sapiente praesentium consequatur. Libero vitae odit maxime repudiandae obcaecati.
  </p>

  <p class="string">
    lorem
  </p>
</div>

<button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

Alternatively, here's a snippet using a function with closures to handle the button click.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", ToggleHelper());

function ToggleHelper() {
  const colorClasses = ["green-bg", "blue-bg"];
  const toggleBGArr = elem => isBlue(elem) ? 
    colorClasses.slice().reverse() : colorClasses;
  const getContainer = () => document.querySelector(colorClasses.map(c => `.${c}`));
  const isBlue = elem => elem.classList.contains(colorClasses[1]);
  const textSlicer = elems =>
    elems.forEach(box =>
      box.textContent = box.textContent.length >= 20 ?
        box.textContent.slice(0, 20) : box.textContent);
      
  return evt => {
    const origin = evt.target;
    if (origin.classList.contains("toggle")) {
      const container = getContainer();
      container.classList.replace
        .apply( container.classList, toggleBGArr(container) );
      isBlue(container) && textSlicer(document.querySelectorAll(".string"));
    }
  };
}
```

```css
.blue-bg {
  background: lightblue;
}

.green-bg {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-bg">
  <p class="string">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    Delectus eveniet libero voluptate sunt distinctio iste ex, 
    ratione, soluta, labore dolorem laboriosam sapiente praesentium
    consequatur. Libero vitae odit maxime repudiandae obcaecati.
  </p>

  <p class="string">
    lorem
  </p>
</div>

<button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Could you try this please. It may helpful for you :)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".buttonclick").click(function() {
    var myStr = $(".textarea").text();
    var limit = 20;
    if (myStr.length > limit && $('.textarea').hasClass('bg-green')) {
      var strtemp = myStr.substr(0, limit);
      $(".textarea").text(strtemp + '.....');
      $(".textarea").css('background-color', '#0f0');

    }
  });
});
```

```css
.textarea {
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Enter Text and Click the Buttons</h3>
<div class="textarea bg-green">Paragraph of text with multiple white spaces before and after. </div>
<br>
<button type="button" class="buttonclick">click</button>
```